# USB communication issue on newer machines

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, usb

It's been difficult formulate a question for this problem and wasn't sure how much info to provide so I apologize if this seems long-winded.

Win 10 x64

Visual Studio 2019

.NET 4.5.2

C# WPF application
SiLabs driver for USB communication

The application communicates with a device over USB at a user selected sample rate (200Hz-1000Hz) and shows feedback on both the device and the application. A button is pressed in the UI to tell the device to begin broadcasting data. This data is then charted in the app. At some point the user presses another button which tells the device to begin showing feedback for a user-defined period of time. At the same time the application marks the beginning and end of this time period on the chart. This has all worked fine and has been tests on machines up to 10 years old as long as they met the specifications. Within the last year new machines were purchased, a Dell all-in-one and Lenovo Thinkpad. At the highest sample rate (1000 Hz) after clicking the button to begin showing feedback on the device and marking the beginning/end of the time period involved there is a large delay and the device doesn't respond at all.

OK, here's the kicker. If the application is run through the VS IDE, release or debug build, it runs perfectly. This is also true if the IDE is attached post-launch. Using Process Explorer there are additional assemblies loaded after the IDE is attached, namely:

```
    GdiPlus.dll Microsoft GDI+ Microsoft Corporation C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.19041.685_none_faeca4db76168538\GdiPlus.dll
```

Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.dll Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.dll Microsoft Corporation C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\XamlDiagnostics\Framework\x64\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.dll

Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTapBootstrap.dll UNKNOWN_FILE Microsoft Corporation C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\XamlDiagnostics\x64\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTapBootstrap.dll

SMDiagnostics.ni.dll SMDiagnostics.dll Microsoft Corporation C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\SMDiagnostics\c524816902880fd5fabd413da3a7cee3\SMDiagnostics.ni.dll

StaticCache.dat C:\Windows\Fonts\StaticCache.dat

System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll System.Runtime.Serialization.dll Microsoft Corporation C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Runteb92aa12#\8a153a48cab74fecab5ea91a393181ee\System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll

System.ServiceModel.Internals.ni.dll System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll Microsoft Corporation C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Servd1dec626#\2baecc7ee6f667acd4cf570ad7efbdcf\System.ServiceModel.Internals.ni.dll

I have my doubts that any of these assemblies are needed by the application but am definitely open to any and all ideas regarding this issue. TIA.

Comment: Did you attempt to use WireShark to check out what is going on at the USB level? I suggest checking what are the requests being sent just before the delay occurs.

Comment: Another question is the configuraiton of the USB subsystem on the new laptops. What hubs are in between the controller and the port you attach your device to? Are there any other devices on the same hub as the device you experience problems with?